# Is there a good "Laravel way" to escape html when returning json results?

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, xss

I feel like this should be a common problem, but I haven't been able to find an answer for it.  Blade templates make escaping html easy with `{{ $variable }}`, but for outputting json to an ajax request, not so much.

Naturally, I work with an app that does a lot of ajax calls for user inputted data and returns the results as JSON to the client, which renders it in a jQuery DataTable.  So consider this scenario:

```
$contacts = Contact::whereUserId(Auth::id())
                ->select('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'age')
                ->get();

return response()->json($contacts);
```

I want to escape those name fields for html/script injection before rendering them in a DataTable, such as first and last names.  The only way I can think to do it is to loop through each row in the collection, and for each, loop through each field, and if it's a string, use `e()` on it.

Is there something in the Laravel framework to handle this process?  Or a good package?  I'd rather not do it every time `toJson()` runs, since there may be times I don't want to run that, or like if it's an API call and I need to return the raw json data.

Any advice?  I'm currently on Laravel 5.2.

For the record, only a few of my fields are meant to contain html.

UPDATE: As pointed out in the comments, I am using DataTables.  Currently, I use the `render` option, which is just a closure, on each column I want to escape and use a javascript-based strip tags/html entities function.  I kind of felt like I was doing it wrong, that there should be some function to do this automatically in the Laravel framework given how common it is plus the way blade templates are set up, but is this considered an ideal solution then?

Comment: If you're returning this JSON to a Javascript client, the Javascript client needs to worry about properly handling the HTML within it. With Javascript you typically use `elem.textContent = someContent`, and that's it. It will treat the content as **DOM text**, not HTML, and escaping is unnecessary. Escaping on the server is the wrong place to do it.

Comment: Finally, @deceze for the win. This place is waaaay too full of people who don't understand where the escaping should go. Need to make that comment an answer so that it can be accepted.

Comment: Huh.  I had believed that would be insecure somehow, escaping it on the client side.

Comment: jQuery DataTables doesn't escape HTML so that if field contains `<b>Text</b>` it will be shown in bold in a table by default.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com I know, I would have to add a `render` option to each column that I wanted to escape, and run an escaping function.  But I wasn't sure that was really the best way to handle this app-wide.

Comment: It would be best to do it server-side. Also Yajra DataTables for Laravel has `escapeColumns()` method exactly for that.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, it could be done on client side as well as you said with `render` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery DataTables doesn't escape HTML so that if field contains `<b>Text</b>` it will be shown in bold in a table by default.

You can encode HTML entities in your response using the code below:

```
return response()->json(array_map('e', $contacts->toArray()));
```

If you're using Yajra DataTables for Laravel, it has `escapeColumns()` method which you can use to escape HTML entities in some or all columns. For example:

```
return Datatables::of($contacts)
   ->escapeColumns(['first_name', 'last_name')
   ->make(true);
```